# Automation of Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on automation of a deep excel workbook and stuck in creating excel sheets. I have to create some pivot tables from the initial excel sheet and then generate the graphs based on the pivot table. Please suggest me some ways, and suitable technologies, how can I proceed with this ?

Comment: Please provide some info on, Are u using macros? VB script? JAVA? .net?

Comment: I will use macros and VB script in creating graphs after generating the excel. Firstly I have to generate excel and related pivot tables automatically. Which language will be smart enough to automate the excel ?

Comment: All microsoft tech has seemless integration with Excel ...VB Script, VBA, .net......  have a look in to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414244/vba-pivot-table-on-new-sheet

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I"ll get back if I find any doubts.

Comment: Can you please help me with the initiation, I am a beginner so I am not getting a clue how to start ? I only have the initial excel sheet.

Comment: You can get a basic program written for you by Alt + T, M, R. Record your steps. Press Alt + T, M, R to stop recording. Examine the code Excel wrote for you in the VBA IDE (Alt + F11).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Table from the Excel Sheet will be a good idea.
First row of your raw data should be the Field Names or the headers of the table that you wish to create.
Short cut for creating a Table in Excel is to mark the entire data with Headers and press Ctrl T.
Once table is created it's easier to insert a Pivot table linked to your Table. Position your cursor or active cell inside the table and press Alt N V T
Advantage of a creating a Table from your data is that your Pivot table automatically updates if you happen to add data to your Table.
To learn more about Excel try chandoo.org or U tube videos of Mike Girvin.
Cheers!