# Create a new pivot table in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need help with this code to create a new pivot table on a new shit, but there is an error on the part with the first 4 lines of the code , it is a recorded macro and i am really new to VBA code and code overall, i dont know what is really the problem

```
Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable12" _
        , DefaultVersion:=7
    Sheets("Pivot").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable12").PivotFields("Claimable Amount"), "Sum of Claimable Amount", _
        xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Códigos").LayoutForm = _
        xlTabular
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID").Subtotals = _
        Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID").LayoutForm _
        = xlTabular
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("Employee ID"). _
        RepeatLabels = True
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End Sub
```

To have the new pivot table inserted in a new worksheet with the specifics i need to be able to work with it

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out the post below. There is already an
answer there.

[VBA Pivot Table On New Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414244/vba-pivot-table-on-new-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code for what you described. Can you hit F8 several times and get to the line of code that throws the error? If you can't figure it out, see the sample code in the links below.

https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-pivot-table/#2-Create-Pivot-Table-in-New-Sheet

https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/